# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '.core_resource' doesn't exist

Tags: magento-1.9, database

All of a sudden I'm getting the following error.

> There has been an error processing your request SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
>   table or view not found: 1146 Table '.core_resource' doesn't exist

```
Trace:
#0 /lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#4 /lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#5 /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php(133): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('core_resource', Array)
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(423): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Resource->setDbVersion('core_setup', '1.6.0.4.1.2')
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.4.1.2')
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#12 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#13 /index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#14 {main}
```

After a while the above error is replaced by

```
Fatal error: Cannot access property Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website_Collection::$_model in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 430
```

What could be causing this and how can it be fixed?
This has happened before, and it resolved itself, after **clearing cache**.
I've **deleted cache and locks**, doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Its shows that your table is not being created in the Database...

Check your Grid and Form Code Syntax....

Check your Code in Model Folder of Magento 1.9